# Как сделать скачивание файла, после отправки обратной формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

нужно сделать с конкретной формы (т.к. их несколько), чтобы перед скачиванием данные проверялись на заполнение и никак не скачивалось без.

```html
<div class="pop modal_download " id="download" >
    <div class="modal__close modal__close_download">&times;</div>
    <div class="modal__title">Документация</div>
    <div class="modal__subtitle">Для того что бы скачать документацию, заполните форму</div>
    <form  class="modal-feed-form ice-cream"  action="download/Panorama_Sochi_4.pdf"   id="download_form">
        <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Townhouse">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="nlevin99@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="download">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input id="name" class="modal-form__input contackt-form__input_name " name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Имя">
        <input name="phone"  id="phone" class="modal-form__input contackt-form__input_phone " required placeholder="Телефон">
        <input class="modal-form_button modal-form_button_down result" id="input_form" type="submit" value="Скачать документацию">
    </form>
</div>
```

Код ajax

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    // E-mail Ajax Send
    $('form').submit(function(){ // Change
        const th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail.php', // Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function(){
            $(this).find('input').val('');
            $('#consultation, #order, #download').fadeOut();
            $('.overlay, #thanks').fadeIn('slow');

            $('form').trigger('reset');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Форму обратной связи отправляет, а файл не скачивает

Comment: Не нашёл в вашем коде никакого упоминания скачиваемого файла

Comment: @RomanMitasov `download/Panorama_Sochi_4.pdf`

Comment: В таком случае такой подход в корне неверный. Вы отправляете форму по адресу, в котором лежит файл. Из описания того, что вам нужно, я понял, что надо сначала отправить форму методом POST по адресу N, где она будет принята и обработана, а после получить файл методом GET по адресу M, если форма была заполнена верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сразу после успешного отправления формы у пользователя началось скачивание файла, добавьте в `done()` вот такой код:

```js
.done(function() {
  // ...
  if (true /* условие, что форма отправлена верно */) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    // '/download.png' это URL скачиваемого файла
    link.setAttribute('href', '/download.png');
    link.setAttribute('download', 'download.png');
    link.click();
  }
  // ...
});
```

Решение взято [отсюда](https://snipp.ru/jquery/download-in-browser)